# How manage header chunks in Buddy algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, memory-management

I'm working on a tcmalloc for learning memory management.
But there is still a part that i can't figure out.
When you use [buddy algorithmn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddy_memory_allocation), how you manage header chunks when you split or merge bloks? I mean, when you merge two chunks, you don't need two header anymore, so what? You just free the memory? You can't free memory space between two chunks if i'm not wrong.

So any help or links is welcome ^^

Thanks !

EDIT:
After spoke with some people, i found out that i need to manager chunk header in another memory area. It's right? How can i do that?

Comment: When you merge the block with its buddy you're effectively reconstituting the original block from which the two buddy blocks were created so the header is subsumed into the original "whole" block.

Comment: Yes but how do that? I can't imagine that. I alloc the maximun size for a header and fragment it when i split? Google use something a little special as if there was no header.

Answer (score 0):

I think one part where you might be getting confused is that there's nothing wrong with overwriting the memory where existing headers are stored. In fact, that's what you want to effectively have happen when you coalesce blocks through a merge in addition to inserting new headers on the fly when you split them.

So if we imagine a simplified example where your order-0 blocks are 64 bytes and your largest, order-3 blocks are 256 bytes, then we start with a 256-byte order-2 block like so:

```
[nil<-header1->nil][data1 ...............................]
```

Where `data1` is the memory made available to the client requesting memory to overwrite as he pleases. As a basic example, let's also say you're using 8-byte headers for 64-bit alignment which store integral offsets to the adjacent previous/next block along with a flag indicating which blocks are used and their size (a block is a buddy if it has a next/prev offset to it making it adjacent and matches the same size). Initially those values can be -1 to indicate that there are no adjacent blocks available.

Another way to look at that initial 256-byte order-2 block is something that needs to have enough space for 4 order-0 blocks. So the total memory size of the block should be 256+4*8 bytes, or 288 bytes.

Now let's say the client requests to allocate 128 bytes. In that case, we need to split our 256-byte order-2 block into two order-1 blocks, halving their size. In the process, we can insert a new header in the middle, 128 bytes after the address where `data1` begins.

```
[nil<-header1->header2][data1........[header1<-header2->nil][data2]........]
```

This new `header2` should have a `next` offset of -1 to indicate that it's at the end of the list with a previous offset pointing back to `header1` for its buddy. `header1` should also update its next offset to point to `header2` and we should make both have a size of 128 bytes (half the size of what `header1` originally stored before the block was split).

We can then return the pointer to `data1` for the client to write to as he wishes and also mark `header1` as being in use.

Now let's say the client then requests to free that block. In this case, we can subtract 8 bytes from the memory address he passes in to get from `data1` to `header1`. We can also see from `header1` that its neighbor is `header2` which is currently unused while having the same size as `header1`, making it a buddy suitable for merging. So that's when we can merge.

This process is very simple. `header1's` next offset is simply overwritten with `header2's` next offset which is -1, and its size is doubled. We'll still have that `header2` data lingering around in memory until the user overwrites it (unless it's a `calloc` style operation where we write 0s to overwrite it ourselves). Yet it's just a lingering artifact floating around in memory that's now intended to be overwritten.

```
[nil<-header1->nil][data1 ...............................]
```

This is describing a fairly basic implementation and I only covered one possibility of how to handle splitting and merging. You can also get fancy and store headers in a separate memory space, but that will often invite a bit more processing overhead with a search of some sort to fetch the appropriate header information from a pointer. It can be useful for reduced memory overhead with your smallest order-0 blocks (mainly by avoiding alignment requirements), but a bit more difficult to make fast. When the header is stored in the same place, we can do something as basic as a simple subtraction to get to the header contents.